drop-down( programmatically selecting a option in drop-down menu
so I was trying to click a dropdown option of a site there is the code :
so I was trying to click a dropdown option of a site there is the code :
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-8">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-269" role="option">
<span class="select2-match">Good</span></div></li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-270" role="option">Very 
<span class="select2-match">Good</span></div></li></ul>

I have used click(), key down, key up, and event handler it only returns undefine. somehow I managed to open the drop menu but I can't click on the option Mainly they have used the input tag, not a select tag so I can't use selectedindex also not working. I am new to these topics .somebody have any idea how can we do this?:)
To open the dropdown option,I'm using:
const input =document.querySelector("#s2id_autogen8")
input.value = 'Good'

const event = new Event('input', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
})

input.dispatchEvent(event)
~~


You set the value of the dropdown to the value of the option you want to select, you don't click on the option.

The Select2 plugin may have its own method for selecting an option.
